# How to access a function's object in another file in JS

Tags: javascript

I have an arrow function that get exported and used in another file (I'm using React, but it doesn't matter). In my function I have an object with some properties. However I can't seem to access the object.

I tried 2 approaches:

## 1. Export in export:

I tried exporting inside an existing export, but that didn't work:

```
export const TextComponent = ({ text }) => {
    export const Props = {
        text: [text]
    }
    return <p>{Props.text}</p>
}
```

## 2. Trying to access it in another file without an export

like:

```
export const TextComponent = ({ text }) => {
    const Props = {
        text: [text]
    }
    return <p>{Props.text}</p>
}

//file 2

TextComponent.Props ...
```

None of these seem to work, is there a way to access this object from a function in another file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try to export the object and then inside your function you can perform the property assignment for that object. Something like this:

```
export const Props = {};
export const TextComponent = ({ text }) => {
    Props.text = [text]
    return <p>{Props.text}</p>
}
```

Comment: You can do this in JS, however, it makes no sense, if you are working in a React environment you shouldn´t use Props this way